# Why is typed function definition not strickly checking return of function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-eslint

I am trying to get property typed function based on generated schema from OpenAPI and I have encountered weird type-checking behavior.

I have following object (simplified for showcasing) where route 'test' can either have response 200 with body { code: number; }.

```js
interface TestPayloads {
    test: {
        responses: {
            200: {
                code: number;
            };
            204: never
            }
    }
}
```

Then I have typed response defined as following

```js
type OperationWithResponse = { responses: any };
type OperationId = keyof TestPayloads;


export type TypedResponse<T extends OperationId> = TestPayloads[T] extends OperationWithResponse
  ? Promise<TestPayloads[T]['responses']['200']>
  : Promise<void>;
```

I also create TypedHandler, which represents function with TypedResponse return type

```js
export type TypedHandler<T extends OperationId> = () => TypedResponse<T>;
```

Not to actual issue. When I just type function with TypedHandler I get correct suggestion to what return.

```js
const funtionOk: TypedHandler<'test'> = async () => {
    return {
        code: 123
    };
}
```

But if I add extra parameter I am not getting expected error.

```js
const funtionNotOk: TypedHandler<'test'> = async () => {
    return {
        code: 123,
        // Should show error Type '{ code: number; message: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ code: number; }'.
        message: "test"
    };
}
```

But again if I add extry type to return of my function, I get expected strict typechecking.

```js
// Extra type (repeating from TypeHandler) for return
const funtionExpectedError: TypedHandler<'test'> = async ():TypedResponse<'test'> => {
    return {
        code: 123,
        // correctly shows error here
        message: "test"
    };
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or I should do extra to be only use TypedHandler, without repeating type for response to get correct strict type checking?

Example can be replicated in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=61&ssc=37&pln=11&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBYIZBRkZIMJY4fSoWhMaDwBjcYQAb0UJRKCkEqHyoC5PJFoAJBEagn0guForlACYAAyKmXcuXqkoIbiQQWcdiIaTfADcao1JQAviazTylQAWXWQPRkU1m80ut1u4KodqgADyGzqDU44F2j30Es4UtAAF4hWLw5LpWJOHhQJbFN6iH6A-VGgBJVyx%20KQQypen8pl4FlswQm4IQ%20BkGiZ3DtbhhwQRqUAHhw4NWCh4wn930D%20e4AD4Y94GZXq%20yANo4AC6-cH7Ozo9zwdDCcjShKAH46GxEEJIL3Z8zWYuVwuAOTixOCe-Lh9KxWvidqwW0U-n7sdHgChJzrBsmzQH19m4AAJFwsV7NcUQ3EcyDHTgCynWMAAoAEoYynaCOy7C8cAnOtFAQSMaGSLht19eJBWguCeAQ%208%20VQe8sLEY5zFAPCCKFF0nFQfEvFlOUtR1UAAEZ5QAZndE1PUoyUaLooMADlBgYpi2xY7g2I4rjpwYXjYH4-DoynCT41EshxJdEUpMFOT5N4JyeRUYhMA4aIrl8iRwTINhsX2UB7w5NFtV1fVDTII1QGQQRAWYaT%20UoThmES817xEYQBhoMy5GYTgGGkdwwRbCKopc-o4uNNN7yCDVktS6SACIOI6pTFBUqj%20RxDTGgAUXWSBYAUbgRpCxs9KIWD4O%20bt2IZEzYzMk4LLw-IiL3HtVv5dabOEyB7McjU6rcjzWv0drBS6hkepFdN%20sleB3ACFlmGwhhcnkIbtiDBi8Nwk0Bo%20yAvvgH6-oYAHaKBxptNQEHcLB1TI0h6HYf%209Skc4BiKmYeHOFBusVBwZoPAcpLG2cYF2GbO5GCy9gGDS-hYGgdREnK%20A9BELwOrGhhEAWfQOqSbEOvABxOOETTIAkDqghUX0vjId4pX4NKjlQRwpvGVMnEQAXhiwfQUAQRBoWES4vkkRt-NEQx8XmRgWDYLhuBa0AgA)

I have tried different combination handler type, but can not get the typing to work.